# Gstreamer: How to link a request pad (sink) and static pad (source)

Tags: gstreamer, pad

Trying to do the linking for tee to a queue. Here is what i do in the program codes

Program snippets
/// create the tee pad template
tee_src_pad_template = gst_element_class_get_pad_template (GST_ELEMENT_GET_CLASS (tee),
"src_%u");

```
if(!tee_src_pad_template)
    g_print("thread Live: no tee_src_pad_template \n");

/// request the 2 pad
tee_pad = gst_element_request_pad (tee,
                                   tee_src_pad_template,
                                   NULL,
                                   NULL);
queue_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad (queue, "sink");

/// verify the object is created
if(!tee_pad)
    g_print(" no tee_pad \n");

if(!queue_pad)
    g_print("no queue_pad \n");

/// link the pads together
GstPadLinkReturn  ret  = gst_pad_link (tee_stream_pad, queue_stream_pad);
g_print(" Link return %d \n", ret);
```

The program compiles but there is error at the link pad stage, the value returned is -4

```
 Link return -4
```

Check out on the meaning of GstPadLinkReturn value. Just wonder what causes the following

```
GST_PAD_LINK_NOFORMAT (-4) – pads do not have common format
```

And what does it mean they do not have common format? Aren't they neutral linkers?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to figure out the common problem as I linked the wrong element type

```
GST_PAD_LINK_NOFORMAT (-4) – pads do not have common format
```

means exactly what it is, that the pads type is compatible

Comment: Ok, so how does one to get "compatible pad types" here?  I have virtually the same code written as you started with.  I'm not following how to link a tee pad to a queue pad.

Comment: @BuvinJ I do not quite recall the answer...but do remember I have probably make a silly error... maybe i link a sink pad with a sink pad (using the wrong pad template..) ... or link to a wrong element (not a peer element).. something along the line....you can check the pad linking with gst_pad_can_link

Comment: Thanks for the response. I certainly understand not remembering all the details of something 6 months later! I assumed that not having a "common format" meant the "caps" don't align.  Yet, it seemed that caps cannot be set on a queue?  I did find, however, that I could use `gst_element_link` on those same tee and queue components (if I redesigned my code a bit), to avoid a call to `gst_pad_link`.  That was confusing! I'm trying to move forward with my new approach, but wish I understood why my first failed. (I.e which closely resembles your post, and produced the same error)

Comment: @buvinJ Maybe set the caps for the gst_element_request_pad? just throwing in ideas

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did (sort of) solve the problem. I've come to believe that issue was that I had *downstream* elements with different caps.  After unlinking some components which were bound to the other side of the queue, `gst_pad_link` worked between the tee the queue.  I don't entirely understand why though.  My best guess is that if the pipeline is going to fail *anywhere*, `gst_pad_link` is going to report an error? But that doesn't necessarily mean the two elements being *directly* linked are the incompatible pieces to the puzzle?

Comment: @buvinj my guess is probably maybe caps negotiation went wrong... just thinking in your situation... probably read the log file or the dot diagram to see what went wrong